# How to make a connection between models in N:N relation on Prisma

Tags: node.js, authentication, prisma

I am developing an auth-api in NodeJS and Prisma that contains a Role table and a Permission table in an N:N relationship

I want to link a permission to a role but I can't do this when I'm creating the role

My models:

```
model permission {
  id              Int               @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  name            String            @unique
  description     String
  created_at      DateTime          @default(now())
  permission_role permission_role[]
}

model permission_role {
  permission_id Int
  role_id       Int
  permission    permission @relation(fields: [permission_id], references: [id])
  role          role       @relation(fields: [role_id], references: [id])

  @@id([permission_id, role_id])
  @@index([role_id], map: "permission_role_role_id_fkey")
}
```

And my function in RoleController

```
const role = await prisma.role.create({
                data: {
                    name,
                    description,
                    permission_role: {
                        role_id:this.id,
                        permission_id:existPermission.id
                    }
                }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I alredy had solved. The problem was the way of how I was trying to connect the two models.
It didn't need the `role_Id`, just the permission_id, then Prisma make all the process

My controller function became

```
const role = await prisma.role.create({
                data: {
                    name,
                    description,
                    permission_role:{
                        create:{
                            permission_id:permission
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```